# How can we have a false return in array_walk?

Tags: php, arrays

In which case we will have false as return in `array_walk()`. In fact, in the official documentation they said:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on ***failure***.

Even, if I test:

```
 $array = [];
 var_dump(array_walk($array, function($val) {return $val;}));
 // bool(true)
```

Comment: Well it returns `false` when it can't iterate through all array elements I guess

Comment: Interesting, supplying an integer as the first value causes a warning and the return is `NULL`; likewise for supplying an invalid callback as the second parameter. I cannot figure out how to make it `false` `:-/`

Comment: From [`PHP_FUNCTION(array_walk)`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L1526), the function returns `true` or `null`, and the result of the call to `php_array_walk()` (which can return a failure) is not tested. So, it seems that `false` is never returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this function always returns `true`. Even if it will generate a warning, it still will return `true`. Consider the following code:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];

// Warning:  array_walk(): Iterated value is no longer an array or object
$result = array_walk($array, function ($i) use (&$array) {
    var_dump($i); // => int(1)
    $array = $i;
});

var_dump($result); // => bool(true)
```

So even though array was not iterated over completely and a warning has generated the result still `true`.

If I am not mistaken in the [PHP source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a886ca920f20c3b711715808614fc8699a9ad69f/ext/standard/array.c#L1520) there is no `false` return.

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8aef7ff32f591c07783d2607539fd551362917b).

Comment: As @MonkeyZeus pointed out, the function also can return `null`: https://3v4l.org/cC0LR

Comment: @Syscall, thank you for pointing out. I will try to look into the source code more deeply. From the top of the head `null` is not a return of a function, but a placeholder for the result when the function failed to be executed at all. But this is my naive view, so might be wrong.

Comment: From PHP8, you no longer receive the `null` because the Warning has been promoted to a Fatal error.